# Does anyone know how message.framework and mime.framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, private

I need for my iPad app, that will not be send to AppStore because it is only for personal use, these private frameworks for send an email with inline image (image inside of my app that I can't upload to a server).
I was able to successfully import them but now I really don't know how to use them. My big problem is how to connect message to my MFMailComposeViewController?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use private frameworks to attach an image to an email. `MFMailComposeViewController` has the `-addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method which will allow you to attach an image or any other file.

Comment: Ehm like I'm wrote I don't need to attach it but insert it inside the email as inline image

Comment: In that case, you would have to take the image data and then encode it as Base64, then embed that in the HTML of the email.